# How to route URL's with koa-router

Tags: javascript, koa-router

I am trying to route a URL which I am calling `fetch` on to a function using `koa-router`.
The URL ends with `/email/example@example.com`, and is supposed to fetch a user object by their email. The router object defines:

`router.get( uri_prefix+'/email/:email', readUserByEmail);`

The definition of the function is as follows:

```
async function readUserByEmail (ctx, next) {
  try {
    // get params
    let _EMAIL = ctx.params.email;
    ...
}
```

I know that the router works for other functions (such as get user by id), however, it doesn't seem to invoke the function `readUserByEmail`.

I am not sure what the problem is - whether I am not defining the route correctly, or the function (in terms of parameters), or maybe there are other files I should edit, or maybe something else.

Any help or tips would be appreciated

Comment: Is “/email/test” being routed to readUserByEmail?

Comment: I tried a generic string as the email (that does not include a '@' or a '.') but it still did not route correctly

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case was:

The changes that I was making to the routes were correct, but they were all local (while the actual app was configured to interact with the server that is online), therefore it didn't work.

It is worth looking at where the changes you made run and where the application itself runs.